# Error when put <BrowserRouter> and useRoutes(routes) in A function component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx

I'm using `react-router-dom` in my react app.
When I use:

```js
function App() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>{ useRoutes(routes) }</BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```

And I got error message: `Uncaught Error: useRoutes() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.`

I've searched how to fix it and change my code's structure to:

```js
function App() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter><Foo/></BrowserRouter>
    );
}
function Foo() { 
    return useRoutes(routes)
}
```

The code works properly.

As a starter, I can't tell the exact difference between the two snippet above, could someone please help?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> Uncaught Error: useRoutes() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.
> ```

All this message is saying is that there needs to be a routing context provider higher in the ReactTree than this `App` component that is trying to consume it when using the `useRoutes` hook.

A clearer bad example:

```
function App() {
  const routes = useRoutes(routes); // <-- (2) but needed here!
  return (
    <BrowserRouter> // <-- (1) context provided here
      {routes}
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Here you can clearly see that the router is ***below*** the `App` component and there is no routing context provided to `App`.

This is why the second snippet works, it's providing the routing context *higher* than the component consuming it.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter> // <-- (1) context provided here
      <Foo/> // <-- (2) context consumed here
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

function Foo() { 
  return useRoutes(routes);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another example where the error was thrown and was fixed thanks to @drew-reese's explanation:

create-react-app builds the following TypeScript test file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';

test('renders learn react link', () => {
  render(<App />);
  const linkElement = screen.getByText(/learn react/i);
  expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

The fix is to include BrowserRouter

```
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
```

and to wrap `<App />` to get the routing context:

```
render(<BrowserRouter><App /></BrowserRouter>);
```